# Add attribute to the body failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have an asp.net web page. The code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Works.Login" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
   <head runat="server">
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/source/style.css" />
   </head>
   <body id="PageBody" runat="server">
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div style="text-align: center" >
```

And in code behind I want to add something to the body attribute.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
        if (PageBody != null) 
        { 
            PageBody.Attributes.Add("class", "some_image");
```

However I found it doesn't work at all. I stepped through into the code and found there is an exception.

> InnerText = '((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)(((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)(PageBody)))).InnerText'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'}

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the exception message?

Comment: InnerText threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do in the PageLoad, It works.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PageBody != null)
        {
             PageBody.Attributes.Add("class", "myClass");
        }
    }
```

EDIT : Full code to show this is working (since the op is doubtfull abt it)

My ASPX page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="SO.WebForm4" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    body
    {
        background-color:Olive;
    }    
    .myClass
    {
        background-color:Orange;

    }
    </style>

</head>
<body id="PageBody" runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <h2>Testing styles</h2>
       <p>If the bg color is Orange, code is working</p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SO
{
    public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PageBody != null)
            {
                PageBody.Attributes.Add("class", "myClass");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the output

[image]

Comment: No, the exception still exists. I tested it. Also please see http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet/2006-07/msg01325.html

Comment: @Love: Is it a Master page ? then you should have mention in the queston .If it is a normal page, It will work. I tested it

Comment: They are same whatever master or normal, I tested in a normal page but no lucky. Can you tested it on your machine? I use asp.net 3.5.

Comment: Have you stepped into the code to look at the PageBody.InnerText?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
PageBody.Attributes["class"] = "some_image";
```